# Nativescript - file system overwrite not working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, filesystems, nativescript, firebase-storage

I'm new to NativeScript.

I'm using `nativescript-plugin-firebase` to download the photo of the user and save it into `/data/user/0/{APP_ID}/files/telerik-logo-downloaded.png`.

**Firebase Storage Native API Example:**

```
var fs = require("tns-core-modules/file-system");

// let's first determine where we'll create the file using the 'file- system' module
var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
var logoPath = documents.path + "/telerik-logo-downloaded.png";

// this will create or overwrite a local file in the app's documents folder
var localLogoFile = documents.getFile("telerik-logo-downloaded.png");

// now download the file with either of the options below:
firebase.storage.downloadFile({
  bucket: 'gs://n-plugin-test.appspot.com',
  remoteFullPath: 'uploads/images/telerik-logo-uploaded.png',
  localFile: fs.File.fromPath(logoPath),
  localFullPath: logoPath
}).then(
  function (uploadedFile) {
    console.log("File downloaded to the requested location");
  },
  function (error) {
    console.log("File download error: " + error);
  }
);
```

When there's a change(e.g. user uploads a new photo), I will download the photo with the **Firebase Storage Native API** and overwrite the existing one.

```
var localLogoFile = documents.getFile("telerik-logo-downloaded.png");
```

this code above should overwrite the local file if it's existing.

In the result, the new photo will be shown on iOS but not Android. For Android, it's still the old photo.

May anyone help? Thank you~

Comment: hello @felicia, may I ask how do you load the photo?

Comment: Thanks for replying @vann_goh, this way `img.src = logoPath`, is there any problem?

Comment: may you try to change the way you load the photo as I comment below? Tell me if it works ;)

Comment: Oh yeah!!! Thank you soooo much @vann_goh!!! It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is the way you load the imageSource.

It should already overwrite the file, try this

```
img.src = imageSource.fromFile(logoPath)
```

instead of

```
img.src = logoPath
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

With Android image won't be refreshed if it's the same url again. Try setting the image source to `null` and then set it back to your path again.

Comment: I found the answer above, also I wish I could upvote your answer as well! Thank you sooo much @Manoj